# Manually validate using javax.validation

Tags: java, validation

I have a stupidly complex object that may (or may not) contain an email address (or phone number, or any number of other Json encoded stuff). My issue is that i want to use javax.validation to validate it.

My understanding is that i need to do Bean validation and create my own annotation for the validation, no issue there. However, i want to use the @Email validation (just like i do everywhere else in my app) how do i go about manually invoking the validate?

Is it best practice to just write a method like such and call it from the isValid method?

private void validateEmail(@Email String email) {}

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `javax.validation.Validator` to validate the whole object or a specific field, like this:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
    var obj = new MyObject("invalidEmail");
    var validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    // 2 violations: email & name
    System.out.println(validator.validate(obj));
    // 1 violation: email
    System.out.println(validator.validateProperty(obj, "email"));
}

class MyObject {
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public MyObject(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```